# How to change the layout of List Tile on selection?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list view. I want to change the Tile layout if the index is selected.Something like this [image with ListTile Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP5v6.png) and what i have developed [what i have able to achieve till now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQGky.png). On selecting the List Tile layout should get changed as show in the first link.

```
Widget _buildRow() {

 return

   Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Divider(
        height: 35.0,
      ),
            ListTile(
              leading: new Text(
                "Set 1",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.double,
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway-Medium',
                ),
              ),
              title: Center(
                child: new Text(
                  "40 Lbs",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.double,
                    fontFamily: 'Raleway-Medium',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: (_isFavorited
                    ? Icon(Icons.check_circle)
                    : Icon(
                        Icons.check_circle_outline,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                iconSize: 35.0,
                splashColor: Colors.tealAccent,
                onPressed: _toggleFavorite,
              ),
            ),
      Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10.0),
           child: Divider(
             height: 40.0,
           ),
         ),
         Center(
           child: IconButton(
             icon: (_isFavorited
                 ? Icon(Icons.cancel)
                 : Icon(
               Icons.cancel,
               color: Colors.grey,
             )),
             color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
             iconSize: 35.0,
             splashColor: Colors.tealAccent,
             onPressed: _resetSetData,
           ),
         ),

       ],
      ),

      ListTile(

              title: Center(
                child: new Text(
                  "10 reps",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.double,
                    fontFamily: 'Raleway-Medium',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    ],
  );
}

void _toggleFavorite() {
   setState(() {
    if (_isFavorited) {
     _isFavorited = false;
   } else {
     _isFavorited = true;
  }
});
}

void _resetSetData() {
  setState(() {
    if (_isFavorited) {
    _isFavorited = false;
  } else {
    _isFavorited = true;
  }
});
 }
```

What will be the best way to achieve this UI?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the list tile using a container and use bool to maintain the state of the tile so that you can change the color of List tiles.Thanks